# How to I convert the output of an md5 hash into a float between 0 and 1

Tags: ruby

In A/B testing, it's fairly common to split based on modulo arthimetic, but that often causes overlapping experiments, i.e. if you used id % 2 == 0 as your split criteria, one set of users would be consistently getting into control or experiment.

A solution I've heard about is to use hashing. I want to concatenate a `user_id` with an experiment name, hash it, and then convert that into a float between 0 and 1. I know how to do the hashing (`Digest::MD5::hexdigest('test').to_i(16)`) but I'm confused on the next steps for conversion to a float between 0 and 1.

What are the steps?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  Also, what version of ruby are you using?  I get the following output on ruby-2.3.6 `Digest::MD5::hexdigest('test').to_i(16) #=> 12707736894140473154801792860916528374`

Comment: Next step is to convert to a float between 0 and 1.

Comment: Digest::MD5::hexdigest returns a 128 bit string, which requires 2 ^ 128 = 3.4028237e+38 different numbers. On the other hand, Ruby's `Float` usually has a precision of 2.2204460492503131e-16. If you try to map the hash to float, much of your information would be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution by porting the code that's listed here: http://blog.richardweiss.org/2016/12/25/hash-splits.html

```
test_id_digest = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user_id + experiment_name)
test_id_first_digits = test_id_digest[0..5]
test_id_final_int = test_id_final_int = test_id_first_digits.to_i(16)

ab_split = test_id_final_int.to_f/0xFFFFFF
```

The basic idea is to create the digest, then take the first six letters, then divide by the largest six digit hex string.

The blog post referenced goes into verifying the randomness of this solution.